# I try to get data once from firestore but I recieve it thrice for each document in a collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

As I have mentioned in the code (in image) I try to get all documents for once but I get it thrice for each document.

```
  const docs = await db.collection("programs").get();
  docs.forEach((doc) => console.log(doc.data()));
```

Comment: You are retrieving all the documents in your collection. Can you please paste your complete code in text format ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have mentioned the code above. I am pasting it again...

Comment: const docs = await db.collection("programs").get();
  docs.forEach((doc) => console.log(doc.data()));

Comment: It's hard to tell if there is any issue with your React JS code that is calling the `fetchPrograms()` function thrice, please post your complete code.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to use componentDidMount in my component where I call this action creator. Now I fixed this